# Diferença entre datas em meses com retorno decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia !

Estou utilizando o comando abaixo e o resultado retornado é 6.
Na verdade, observando bem as datas, ainda não fechou exatamente os 6 meses, acho que através dessa função não estão sendo considerados os dias, e isto está me gerando um problema. Será que teria alguma forma de retornar nesse caso somente o inteiro 5 ou com decimal mesmo, 5,8 por exemplo ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112), '20180222', DATEDIFF(MM, '20180222', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112))
```

> ```
> 20180817  20180222    6
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comecei a pesquisar mas não achei uma forma de melhorar a precisão do *datediff* via parâmetro, então resolvi partir pra lógica:

```
declare @diferencaDias int, @meses int
select @diferencaDias = CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, '20180222', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)), '20180222'), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)) AS VARCHAR(2)),
  @meses = DATEDIFF(MM, '20180222', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112))


select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112), '20180222', case when @diferencaDias < 0 then @meses - 1 else @meses end
```

O código checa a diferença em dias e em meses entre as datas. Considerando os *6 meses* do exemplo, caso ainda não tenha sido completo (como por exemplo dia 17), é subtraído *1* do total de meses; sendo dia 22, é retornado o total calculado pela função.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente esta solução !  Valeu !

Answer (score 2):

Não é exato, porém chega perto do que você quer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112), '20180222', CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, '20180222', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)) AS numeric(14,2)) / 30
```

Estou dando um cast de numeric (14,2), ou seja, 14 de comprimento antes da virgula e 2 casas decimais, e divindo os dias em 30 (um mês), assim resultando em 5.86666

Não é exato pois existem meses com 30 e meses com 31, e fevereiro tem 28..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é como você falou, a bronca é a precisão (meses com 28, 29 ou 31 dias podem não trazer o resultado esperado)

Answer (score 0):

Para ter a diferença em decimais, você precisa calcular em horas, e ir convertendo depois: multiplica por 24 para saber em dias e por 30 depois para saber em mêses:

```
 select cast(datediff(hour,convert(datetime,'20180222'),
                      getdate())AS DECIMAL(6,2))/(24*30)
```

Aqui o fiddle funcionando: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/30291)